# Resolving incompatibilities between the Spring.NET and NHibernate assemblies

Tags: .net, nhibernate, assemblies, spring.net

I am trying to develop a .NET Web Project using NHibernate and Spring.NET, but I'm stuck. Spring.NET seems to depend on different versions of the NHibernate assemblies (maybe it needs 1.2.1.4000 and my NHibernate version is 1.2.0.4000).

I had originally solved similar problems using the "bindingRedirect" tag, but now even that stopped working.

**Is there any simple solution to resolve these inter-library relations?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I too ran into this, frustrated I just grabbed the Spring source and compiled it against the latest NHibernate to make it go away forever.  Not sure if that's an option for you but the 10 minutes that took seems to have saved me a lot of time overall.

Here's the SourceForge link for the Spring Source for all versions: **[Spring Source](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=106751&package_id=115147)**

Comment: You can even download their compiled nightly builds here: http://www.springframework.net/downloads/nightly/

Answer (score 2):

Spring.Net is open source isn't it? Why don't you just download the source, update the reference to the same version of NHibernate you are using and recompile?